# Is it possible to send jpg files over CANbus

Tags: camera, usb, stm32, can-bus

I'm trying to interface a board level USB camera with a STM32 family microcontroller and send the image file to a central computer using CANbus. Just want to know if this is possible/ has been done before and how involved a task it would be.

Answer (score 1):

I worked at a company where we sent live (low-resolution infra-red) video streams over CAN, but towards the end of my time there they shifted towards ethernet.

So it is possible, but certainly not what it is best suited for.  The main advantages of CAN are that it is a multi-point, multi-master bus with built in arbitration.  It is meant for short packets, typically 8 bytes (CAN FD allows you to increase that).

If your camera is USB, why not just get a USB repeater cable or USB-over-ethernet gateway?

If there is already a CAN network in place that you are piggy-backing onto then you need to consider what impact you will have on the existing traffic.

If you are starting from scratch then of course CAN will work but it would be an odd choice.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Would be creating this CAN network from scratch and only for the purpose of image transfer. Would want to use CAN to avoid the need for a router/ethernet switch and for the ability to "daisy chain" cameras together.  Also no need to stream.. only still images would only be transferred infrequently.

Comment: @jfhagler Sounds like CAN FD might be an option then. STM32 CAN controllers seem to have a bad rep, so I'm not sure how up to date they are with CAN technology. Otherwise there's Microchip SAMC which has a very nice, modern controller for classic CAN or CAN FD.

Comment: A little 3 port switch lets you daisy chain ethernet.  The chip is only slightly larger than a CAN transceiver.  Or you can daisy chain dozens of USB hubs for data.  The main problem then becomes power.

Comment: @TomV if there is no other option rather than CAN Bus, would that be possible to join the very 8 bytes of the fragmented file in the correct sequence?

Comment: Yes it would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if its CAN or CANFD (Affects the maximum bulk transfer packet size) you have higher level protocol options to packetise your images and send them over canbus like any other block of data.

For just reguarlar CAN your after part of the standard called J1939.21 Data Link Layer, there are public versions of this floating around online, however due to the agreement when purchasing the standard, I am not able to share the specifics from what I have.

Its on pages 27-28 of the 2001 revision.